# Как сделать фото и сохранить в галереи используя новый API ActivityResultContracts

Tags: android, камера

Хочу сделать фото причем чтоб оно сохранилось в галереи, а я получил uri

```
    val cameraLauncher =
    rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()
    ) { isOK -> ...}
     cameraLauncher.launch(file.toUri())
```

Проблема в том что Я могу, сохранить только в песочнице приложения используя androidx.core.content.FileProvider, но мне нужно, чтоб сделаное фото, было потом доступно в галлереи,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов:

```
    fun addImageToGallery(filePath: String) {
            val uri =
                contentResolver.insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    createContentValues()
                )
    
            if (uri != null) {
                FileInputStream(filePath).use { input ->
                    contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri).use { output ->
                        val buffer = ByteArray(BUFFER_SIZE)
                        while (true) {
                            val numBytesRead = input.read(buffer)
                            if (numBytesRead <= 0) {
                                break
                            }
                            output?.write(buffer, 0, numBytesRead)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    private fun createContentValues(): ContentValues {
            return ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "image")
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, IMAGE_JPEG)
            }
        }
```

Передаем в качестве аргумента path нашего файла в addImageToGallery, contentResolver вернет нам uri, по полученному uri записываем файл.
Для android API < 29 нужно запрашивать разрешение на WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: тоесть идея, то что делаем фото, создается файл в нашем хранилище, и потом мы его уже копируем в галлерею?

Comment: да, используем временный файл в песочнице, который позже помещаем в галлерею